# How to add count down timer in notifications Flutter? End time is provided in the push notification

Tags: android, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-local-notification

Need to add CountDown in notifications

For example, Sales ends in 05:02:23   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e11Fy.jpg)

like this

I tried implementing this with dart Streams. I am not able to stop / close the stream when Notification action is pressed.

Packages used:
flutter_local_notifications
firebase_messaging

Listens to stream and updates notification

```
notificationWithTimer(DateTime time, RemoteMessage message) {
    streamController = countdownTimer.notificationTimer(time);
    var notificationWithTimer = streamController.stream;
    notificationWithTimer.listen((event) async {
      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        message.notification.hashCode,
        '${message.notification?.title}',
        '${message.notification?.body}... ${event.toString()}',
        await notificationDetails(
          image: '${message.notification?.android?.imageUrl}',
          actions: [
            const AndroidNotificationAction(
              'cancel',
              'Cancel',
            ),
          ],
        ),
        payload: jsonEncode(message.data),
      );
    }).onDone(() {
      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancel(message.notification.hashCode);
    });
  }
```

The stream provides Countdown time and return a string

```
StreamController notificationTimer(DateTime endTime) {
    String res = '';
    late String countdownDays;
    late String countdownHours;
    late String countdownMinutes;
    late String countdownSeconds;

    tick(_) {
      difference = endTime.difference(DateTime.now());
      countdownDays = _durationToStringDays(difference);
      countdownHours = _durationToStringHours(difference, format);
      countdownMinutes = _durationToStringMinutes(difference, format);
      countdownSeconds = _durationToStringSeconds(difference, format);
      if (difference <= Duration.zero) {
        timer?.cancel();
        timeStreamController.close();
      }
      res = "$countdownHours:$countdownMinutes:$countdownSeconds";
      if (!timeStreamController.isClosed) timeStreamController.sink.add(res);
    }

    stopTimer() {
      timer?.cancel();
      timer = null;
    }

    if (endTime.isBefore(DateTime.now())) {
      difference = Duration.zero;
    } else {
      difference = endTime.difference(DateTime.now());
    }

    countdownDays = _durationToStringDays(difference);
    countdownHours = _durationToStringHours(difference, format);
    countdownMinutes = _durationToStringMinutes(difference, format);
    countdownSeconds = _durationToStringSeconds(difference, format);

    startTimer() {
      if (difference != Duration.zero) {
        timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), tick);
      }
    }

    timeStreamController = StreamController<String>(
      onListen: startTimer,
      onPause: stopTimer,
      onCancel: stopTimer,
    );
    return timeStreamController;
  }
```

Comment: Can you add code about what you have tried?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Code added in the question